# Is it possible for a warforged to make a magical weapon into their integrated weapon?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, weapons, warforged

Is it possible for a warforged to make a magical weapon into their integrated weapon?

I wanted to make a [*ruidium weapon*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/4698537-ruidium-weapon) (*Critical Role: Call of the Netherdeep*, p. 216) my integrated weapon, but I don't know if it's possible. (I'm asking about the official published version of the warforged in D&D 5e.)

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. In addition to what KRyan mentioned, even in D&D 5e, there were multiple different playtest versions of the warforged (in Unearthed Arcana PDFs) prior to its final version as published in *Eberron: Rising from the Last War* – so if you're asking about 5e, you should specify whether you're asking about the published version or about a particular playtest version.

Comment: I've added the [dnd-5e] tag since you mentioned ruidium weapons (a feature of the new 5e Critical Role adventure *Call of the Netherdeep*). However, I'm not ready to reopen this question, I am not aware of rules for "integrated weapons" for Warforged, could you include more details about which rules you are referring to?

Comment: Are you perhaps referring to the [Armblade magic item](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/215692-armblade)?

Comment: But where are you getting the idea about integrated weapons? The only concept in 5e I'm aware of that is similar to that is the Armblade weapon I mentioned previously.

Comment: Side note, wikidot is a pirate site. They illegally host content one would normally have to pay for.

Comment: nevermind. my friend just told me warforged can't integrate magic items/weapons

Comment: @DylanCovey I've updated my answer, turns out there is a way to do exactly what you are trying to do if you have an Armblade magic weapon.

Answer (score 4):

#### You can turn an Armblade into a Ruidium weapon.

There is no feature called “integrated weapon” in D&D 5e. There is a magical item for Warforged that seems to be a similar idea, the Armblade:

> An armblade is a magic weapon that attaches to your arm, becoming inseparable from you as long as you're attuned to it. To attune to this item, you must hold it against your forearm for the entire attunement period.

It requires attunement by a warforged, and can be any one-handed melee weapon. There is no mechanic for taking an existing magic weapon and turning it into an Armblade like weapon, but you can ask your DM about it.

Now, the rules for Ruidium weapons state:

> Even magic items can be corrupted by ruidium, and using such items comes with a risk.
>
> Weapons and armor can be transformed into ruidium items by infusing them with powdered ruidium, which gives these items a rusty-red coloration. Other items can be transformed into ruidium items after prolonged contact with the mineral; such items have ruidium crystals embedded in them or veins of ruidium running through them.

So if you had an Armblade as well as a source of Ruidium with which to corrupt the Armblade, you would have exactly what you are looking for: a Ruidium Armblade.